# Register new dll with Global Assembly Cache on Win Server 2016 - gacutil.exe is missing

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016

On Windows Server 2016 gacutil.exe is not available and in that case how do I register a custom dll into GAC on this?

This tool is automatically installed with Visual Studio as per https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/gacutil-exe-gac-tool. 
I can not install Visual Studio for this on the server.

Comment: Why not copy from a system that does have Visual Studio?

Comment: Tried, it doesn't work that way.

Comment: You need to copy three files: gacutil.exe, gacutil.exe.config, and gacutlrc.dll from the language subfolder (1033 for example).

Comment: This worked, can you post an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy these three files: gacutil.exe, gacutil.exe.config, and gacutlrc.dll from the language subfolder (1033 for example) from a system that has Visual Studio to the system where you need to run gacutil.

Comment: Thanks this Saved my time.